# Unexpected list behavior in Python

Tags: python, list, behavior

I wanted to reverse a list, and I managed to do so, but in the middle of the work I noticed something strange. The following program works as expected but uncommeting line **list_reversed[i]=list[len(list)-1-i]** and **print(list[i])** (commenting the **last line** of course) leads to a change in **list**. What am I not seeing? My Python version is 3.3.3. Thank you in advance.

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

list_reversed=list

for i in range(0,len(list)):

    #list_reversed[i]=list[len(list)-1-i]
    #print(list[i])

    print(list[len(list)-1-i])
```

Comment: Check out [list slicing](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following:

```
list_reversed = list
```

makes the two variables refer to the same list. When you change one, they both change.

To make a copy, use

```
list_reversed = list[:]
```

Better still, use the builtin function instead of writing your own:

```
list_reversed = reversed(list)
```

P.S. I'd recommend against using `list` as a variable name, since it shadows [the builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that happened, now it all makes sense, thanks for providing with a solution to copy lists.
I found the builtin function while I was learning how to reverse lists but this was more an exercise, thanks for pointing that out nevertheless.
Great suggestion on not using list as a variable name, I haven't programmed Python in a while, but now I remember reading about that.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
list_reversed = list
```

You don't create a copy of `list`, instead, you create a new name (variable) which references the same list you had before.  You can see this by adding:

```
print(id(list_reversed), id(list))  # Notice, the same value!!
```

Answer (score 0):

`list_reversed = list` does not make a copy of list.  It just makes `list_reversed` a new name pointing to the same list.  You can see any number of other questions about this on this site, some list in the related questions to the right.

Answer (score 0):

`list` and `reversed_list` are the same list. Therefore, changing one also changes the other.

What you should do is this:

```
reversed_list = list[::-1]
```

This reverses and copies the list in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

This is about general behaviour of lists in python. Doing:

```
list_reversed = list
```

doesn't copy the list, but a reference to it. You can run:

```
print(id(list_reversed))
print(id(list))
```

Both would output the same, meaning they are the same object. You can copy lists by:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a.copy()
```

or

```
a = [1,2]
b = a[:]
```

Comment: `list` instances don't have a `copy` method (but `dict` instances do)

Comment: Well, doesn't that beat all.  (I've been lobbying for that change for a while now).  I tested with python3.2 and it *doesn't* work.  python3.4 however is a different story.  I don't have python3.3 handy, so I can't test that one.

Comment: I have 3.3.3 on Arch Linux. Thanks for the tip anyway. It could cause me some trouble.