# Python find sum of two numbers from list

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, sum

I am trying to write some code to check if a number is a sum of any two numbers in a list/dictionary and if a number is found, it stops running. However, I am running into some errors. Maybe my logic is wrong but here is my code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

randomNumber = 8

print len(a)
length_of_a = len(a)
for first in range(0,length_of_a -1):
    aa = a
    bb = a
    del bb[first]
    length_of_b = len(bb)
    print bb, length_of_b
    for second in range(0, length_of_b-1):
        print aa[first], bb[second]
        x = aa[first] + bb[second]
        print x
        if x == randomNumber:
            print "Sum Found!"
            break
        else:
            print "No Sum"
```

So my errors:

- aa[first] does not start at 1
- my second array keeps getting smaller when the size should always be 8. Hence, giving me the error "IndexError: list index out of range"
- it doesn't stop when it finds a sum

Any help would be great

Comment: By the way, I don't know if there is another way to remove a number from is list besides del bb[first]. If there is another way, please let me know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected list behavior in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537078/unexpected-list-behavior-in-python)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do and you may have other problems, but sufficiently much of your question boils down to incorrect copying of lists that I feel this is a duplicate right now.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: @honkon: The other way is `bb.pop(first)`.

Comment: I noticed that you unaccepted my answer.  Is something not right?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simply way to do what you want.  It's one line, so you can define it with a `lambda` function:

```
is_sum = lambda seq, x: any(x == y + z for yi, y in enumerate(seq) for zi, z in enumerate(seq) if zi != yi)
```

To use:

```
>>> is_sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 5)
True
>>> is_sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 6)
True
>>> is_sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 12)
False
```

Comment: This does, unfortunately, do away with my favorite bit of code the OP wrote: `randomNumber = 8`

Comment: Oh wow! This makes the rest of my code much easier to write! Thank you!

Comment: It's also important to note that `any()` will return `True` once it reaches the condition. It's kind of like looping and breaking once the answer is found. Hence, this is as efficient as you can get (I was thinking of `set` memberships as an alternative albeit slower solution but I'll pass...)

Comment: this wont work in the case of repeated elements in the sequence eg is_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6], 12),  you can edit so it checks the index instead of the value