# Pandas fillna with inplace=True changes all dataframes that are equal to the one that it is supposed to operate on

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, 1, 0],
                [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                [np.nan, np.nan, 8, 5],
                [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = df
df.fillna(value = df.mean(), inplace=True)
```

Now df2 and df are identical.
How do I avoid changing df2?

Comment: Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537078/unexpected-list-behavior-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a copy of `df` using `copy` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Answer (score 0):

You're "pointing" `df2` to the object that `df` points to. As such, they will be the same.

(The following is from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)).

Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.

To copy a dataframe, do: `df2 = df.copy();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. To summarize, inplace=True will modify any other views on the object.
In my example, to avoid modifying df2, I should use
    df2 = df.copy()
instead of
    df2 = df